# SystemJS does not see exports

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I am trying to use the module system with Es6 and SystemJs.

This is my library code

```
export function sayHello( name ) {
    return `Hello ${name}`;
};
```

And import app.js.

```
import { sayHello } from './lib'
sayHello('Myname');
```

tscongig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES5",
        "outDir": "built",
        "rootDir": "src"
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.4.0",
    "systemjs": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>TypeScript Greeter</title></head>
    <body>
        <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.min.js"></script>
        <script>

          System.import('/built/app.js').then(function(){
                console.log('Done');
            }, function(error){
                console.log(error);
          });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

After running I see the error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

Help me please where to find the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

1. Change the `module` option in your `tsconfig.json` file to `"module": "system"` that should solve the exports problem.
2. Add the following after your `<script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.min.js"></script>` to resolve .js" extension issues.

   ```
   <script>
      var systemResolve = System.resolve;
      System.resolve = function (name, parent) {
        return Promise.resolve(systemResolve.call(this, name, parent))
          .then(function (resolved) {
             if(!resolved.endsWith('.js'))
               resolved += '.js';
               return resolved;
             });
      };
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is necessary to put system instead of commonjs in module section.
But now I have enother problem with the extension.
SystemJs cannot load modules and does not add ".js" extension.
Even after adding  System.defaultJSExtensions = true;